# Plot a surface passing through all the data points in 3D space

Tags: python, matplotlib, plane, matplotlib-3d

I am not really sure if this is possible to do, but essentially I have a list of data corresponding to x, y and z coordinates.

Below image shows the result when I plot these points using a scatter graph (which I created using Python pyplot library).

[image]

My question is, is there any way of plotting the graph of a plane that passes through all of these points instead of plotting them as single points?

When I searched online all I found was resources telling me how to find equation of plane passing though 3 points but as you can see I have many points.

Comment: Is it the case that all your (_x_, _y_) points lie on a regular grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that to have your plot you use this code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

and let's say that you know `nrows`, `ncols`, the number of rows (y) and columns (x) of your base grid.

If these assumptions are correct, then you can use this code to plot a surface connecting the points

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.plot_surface(*(v.reshape(nrows, ncols) for v in (x, y, z)))
plt.xlabel('x') ; plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

or, if you want something fancier,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'),
                       layout='constrained')
surf = ax.plot_surface(*(v.reshape(nrows, ncols) for v in(x, y, z)),
                       cmap='Blues_r', ec='gray', lw=0.2)
plt.xlabel('x') ; plt.ylabel('y')
plt.colorbar(surf)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

The prelude to my code, if you want to check my results, is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nrows, ncols = 63, 126
x = np.linspace(0, 12.5, ncols)
y = np.linspace(-6.2, 6.2, nrows)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
x, y = (V.flatten() for V in (X, Y))
z = np.sin(x)-np.cos(y)

fig, ax = ...
...
```